# Builtin for checking if vec contains specified element

Tags: vector, hhvm, hacklang, vec

Let's say, I have a `vec<int>` containing a list of integers that may be non-continuous (due to element being removed from database).

Example:

```
$occupiedNumbers = vec[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16];
```

Now what I need is to check if this `vec` contains a given number, and if yes, increase it by 1 and repeat checking.

```
$newItemNumber = count($occupiedNumbers);
while (/* check if $occupiedNumbers contains $newItemNumber */) {
    $a++;
}
```

In vanilla PHP there is `in_array()` for this, but would that work for a `vec`? Also, there is a builtin `HH\Vector::linearSearch()` but it's meant to be used with `vec`'s predecessor, `HH\Vector`.

What is the *right* solution to check if a `vec` contains a given value?

Neither HHVM nor Hack docs say about that use case for a `vec`. Also, I'm missing some sort of REPL tool to check it manually off-project without building a whole (possibly faulty) project.

Comment: The HHVM repl is invoked by `hhvm -m debug`. It's a very comprehensive REPL: type "?" at the prompt for commands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The recommendation from the **HHVM/HackLang** guys is to use `C\contains()` as you can read [here](https://docs.hhvm.com/hack/built-in-types/arrays) but you need to install the **HSL** package (`hhvm/hsl`) using `composer`.  This library contains loads of functions to deal with the new array-type structures: `vec`, `dict`, `keyset`.  Those functions in the [HSL Library](https://docs.hhvm.com/hsl/reference/) are prefixed with `C`, `Vec`, `Dict`, `Keyset` and you'll find also `Math`, `Str`, etc., very useful for other needs.

After installing that package it becomes available but typically it is more handy to add `use namespace` to avoid the long prefix:

```html
use namespace HH\Lib\C;
```

This is how you can do it:

```html
$exists = C\contains($occupiedNumbers, $newItemNumber);
```

Comment: Kinda disappointed to see that **key** functions of type manipulation not being builtins and instead pushed to an external library, while legacy functions left as builtins - it's sort of inconsistent :)

Comment: I absolutely agree with @Lukasz032 , I would have expected to be able to use it like `$occupiedNumbers->contains($newItemNumber)` but the **HackLang** guys decided to go the other way.  You had the `Map`, `Set` and `Vector` classes with all those methods built in but they are considering them as "legacy" and discouraging them for some reason.

Comment: @LuckyBrain I agree that HSL should want to be built in, but there's good reason why the collection types are no longer objects (re: the `->`syntax). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59806357/3925507) for details.

Comment: @Lukasz032 as of earlier this week [HSL is now built-in to Hack!](https://hhvm.com/blog/2021/05/04/hhvm-4.108.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you are really looking for the longest continuous interval starting from `count($occupiedNumbers)` then it may be much faster to find its initial index in the sorted list (if it exists), then use direct indexing from there:

```
// `use namespace HH\Lib\{C, Vec};` at top level
$occupiedNumbers = vec[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16];

$sorted = Vec\sort($occupiedNumbers); // if not sorted in general
$size = count($sorted);
$v = $size;
$i = C\find_key($sorted, $w ==> $w === $v);
if($i !== null) {
  for(; $i < $size - 1 && $sorted[$i + 1] === $v + 1; $i++, $v++) {
  }
}
// $i is null | <index of largest number in continuous interval>
```